# Eliminan mis archivos de la web como la base de datos automaticamente

Tags: web, hosting, godaddy

Actualmente utilizo el host de Banahosting y Goddady como dominio, hace unos días la pagina respondía con 404 - Not Found, se restableció la base de datos como los archivos de la web y empezó a funcionar correctamente, pero pasado unos minutos se eliminaban nuevamente.

Un apoyo de porque sucede esto y una posible solución.

Comment: Probablemente tengas que solicitar soporte a tu proveedor. Quizás hay un cron que elimina los archivos en un periodo de tiempo. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.